# Yeoman, npm install errors

Tags: npm, yeoman

Im trying to install angular-fullstack in my terminal to use yeoman,angular, mongodb and express. Unfortunately the command "yo angular-fullstack [app-name]" failed :

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/sss/.npm/coffee-script/1.7.1'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/sss/.npm/coffee-script/1.7.1']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/sss/.npm/coffee-script/1.7.1',
npm ERR!   parent: 'karma-coffee-preprocessor' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/sss/Documents/yeoman-test/angular-fullstack/proj
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/sss/.npm/coffee-script/1.7.1
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/sss/.npm/coffee-script/1.7.1'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've tried to re run the command adding a "sudo" in the beginning of "yo". But I'm running into the same errors. Does anyone know why this isnt working?

Comment: its look like a permissions issue it. try setting the appropriate permissions (use chmod)

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo